# django different user authentication

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, django-views

I have a question concerning different user authentication in Django.

Suppose I have two kind of users, and I want to give them different access to different pages or views. I know that there is @login_required to differentiate login user and visitor. I am just wondering how to differentiate two different kind of logged in users. If using @login_required, I need to do another check to see whether that user is belonged to either group, which may not be the good way to solve the problem.

Any suggestions? Thanks a million!

Comment: What version of `django` you're using?

Answer (score 0):

You can check by

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    #code.....
else:
    #code....
```

or

```
if request.user.is_anonymous:
    #code.....
else:
    #code....
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyModelDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = MyModel

    @login_required
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyModelDetailView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        object = super(MyModelDetailView, self).get_object()
        context = super(MyModelDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        if user.groups.filter(name='group1'):
            context['group_info'] = object.group1_info #unique info for this group
        elif user.groups.filter(name='group2'):
            context['group_info'] = object.group2_info #unique info for this group
        else:
            context['group_info'] = object.anon_info

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```